# Solr highlighting without stop-words for phrases?

Tags: solr, highlighting

I am trying to highlight results in Solr and up until now, it's been a struggle of tweaking here and there... My main concern now is that i got the highlighting phrases thing working, but if i search for something like 
"The World Cup At Brazil: An Unexpected Challenge"

The highlighting field will return:
"World Cup Brazil: Unexpected Challenge"

I think this might be due to the stop words (my field is a 'textgen' type, btw). Is there some kind of parameter to run in the query that would return the entire field highlighted as expected? Or will i have to remove the stopwords filter in the textgen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely due to stopwords. Consider declaring a new fieldtype like textgen, but without the following in it's index or query analyzers:

> ```
>     <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
> ```

Comment: yep, stop words were causing the problems. I just stored the fields as "string", so they appear correctly now, but the search itself is done on a textgen field.