# Solr Highlighting Stopwords

Tags: solr, highlighting, stop-words

schema.xml (the part related to my question):

```
<field name="question" stored="true" type="text" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
<field name="question_highlight" stored="true" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
</fields>
<!-- AND -->
<copyField source="question" dest="question_highlight" />
```

**Notes:** I have stopwords enabled for **fieldType: text**

When I index a document I pass the question field
now when I try to search using this query

```
select?q=question:have fever&hl=true&hl.fl=question_highlight
```

knowing that the word **have** is included in my stopwords list, the word **have** is not highlighted in the results
How can I fix this? I need to highlight stopwords, I checked this post [Solr highlighting without stop-words for phrases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670807/solr-highlighting-without-stop-words-for-phrases) that's why I put **question_highlight** as string but it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution would be using hl.q parameter on highlight field while using q on 
the search field that has StopFilter and hl.q

Comment: I think I've already tried it before
the following query: select?q=question:have fever&hl=true&q=have fever
returns same results with the same highlighting (only for the word fever) should I change anything in my schema.xml?

Comment: hl.q overrides q
see this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1926 to know the syntactical difference then r2a3 :)

Comment: another advice regarding solr once you have a solid schema.xml make changing it your last resolution